# If $AT = TA$ for every continuous compact operator $T$, then $A$ is a multiple of identity

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $H$, let $A: H \rightarrow H$ be a bounded operator. Show that if $AT = TA$ for every continuous compact operator $T : H \rightarrow H$, then $A$ is a multiple of identity operator.

I don't have any idea to prove this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider orthogonal projections of small rank.

Comment: As @DanielFischer comments, but more pointedly, even rank-one operators will distinguish $A$...

Comment: And $A$ need not be assumed bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick some $x$, and let $Ty = {1 \over \|x \|^2}\langle x, y \rangle  x$.
Then $AT x = A x = TA x \in \operatorname{sp} \{ x \}$.
That is, $A x \in \operatorname{sp} \{ x \}$ for all $x$.

For $x \neq 0$, let $\lambda_x$ be defined by $\lambda_x = {1 \over \| x \|^2}\langle x, Ax \rangle $ (so that $Ax= \lambda_x x$). We see that
$x \mapsto \lambda_x$ is constant on $\operatorname{sp} \{ x \}$.

For
completeness, pick some non zero $x_0$ and define $\lambda_0 = \lambda_{x_0}$.

Choose any $y \notin \operatorname{sp} \{ x \}$ (hence $x,y$ are linearly independent), then
$A(x+y) = \lambda_{x+y} (x+y) = \lambda_x x + \lambda_y y$ from which we get
$\lambda_x = \lambda_{x+y} = \lambda_y $. In particular, $x \mapsto \lambda_x$
is constant, and so
$Ax = \lambda_{x_0} x$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this is a beautiful solution.